# AJAX submission of form with file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, file-upload

I'm trying to catch the natural submission of this form and submit it with AJAX instead.

```
<form name="input_form" class="input_form" method="post" action="input?nmap_xml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="input_file" type="file">
    <input name="blah" type="text">
    <input value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is how I'm AJAX posting the form:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.input_form', function(e){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {  
            alert();
        }  
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It "works" except for the fact that the file input is not passed (not even the key `name` is passed, it's just ignored). The `blah` text input is passed fine.

EDIT: 
The question this is supposedly a duplicate does not provide an answer to the question I am asking, although admittedly the title suggest it does.

A hint to a possible answer is giving in the very last comment of the answer, as pointed by user `ahrim`, namely to use `enctype="form/multipart"`. Unfortunately this doesn't work and my problem is exactly the same with that `enctype`.

Comment: @ahrim Please remove the duplicate, I was on that post, it's from 2010 and the accepted answer does not provide an up-to-date answer.

Comment: the update was on April '14

Comment: @ahrim The updated answer is `With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through FormData object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers.`. This does not constitute an answer to the question.

Comment: The last comment of the answer has a helpful link also.

Comment: @ahrim Thank you for your time and help however I must insist, neither the answer nor the last out of those *10* comments provides an answer. The link you mention explains how to get a form working when the only field is the file upload. I'm trying to get *multiple* fields working, with a file among them.